# Scalaz: how to combine monads of type OptionT[State[_], T], so it won't terminate on None

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

I am learning monad transformers and have a problem sequencing them

I created a type `OptionTBitSetState[T]`

I understand this type as **a stateful computation that may fail**

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scala.collection.immutable.BitSet

type BitSetState[T] = State[BitSet, T]
type OptionTBitSetState[T] = OptionT[BitSetState, T]
object OptionTBitSetState {
  def apply[T](option : Option[T]) : OptionT[BitSetState, T] =
    OptionT[BitSetState, T](State[BitSet, Option[T]](_ -> option))

  def apply[T](state : State[BitSet, T]) : OptionT[BitSetState, T] =
    OptionT[BitSetState, T](state.map(_.some))
}
```

I have a function **step** with signature

```
def step(i : Int) : OptionTBitSetState[Seq[Int]]
```

This function should:

1. Check if BitSet inside State contains parameter `i`
2. - If it does not contain: add `i` to BitSet and return `Seq(i, i*10, i*100)`
   - If it contains: fail with `None`

Implementation of function **step**:

```
def step(i : Int) : OptionTBitSetState[Seq[Int]] =
  for {
    usedIs <- OptionTBitSetState(get[BitSet])
    res <- OptionTBitSetState(
      Some(Seq(i, i*10, i*100)).filterNot(_ => usedIs.contains(i))
    )
    _ <- OptionTBitSetState(put(usedIs + i))
  } yield res
```

I want to sequence a list of **step**s in such way that when I evaluate this sequence, I get a list of options as a result. But signature of `sequence` is different. I get an option of lists instead.

e.g.

```
List(1,2,1,3).map(step).sequence.run(BitSet.empty)
```

returns `None`, but what I want is:

```
List(Some(Seq(1, 10, 100)), Some(Seq(2, 20, 200)), None, Some(Seq(3, 30, 300)))
```

Is there any way I can combine `OptionTBitSetState[T]`s, so I will get the behavior I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you are over-complicating the solution by using `OptionT`.

The problem with `OptionT` is that it wants to treat the value inside the monad as either existing or absent, so when you 'collapse' the individual computations into a single State to run it, any single failure must cause the entire thing to fail.

I would just use `State[BitSet,Option[Seq[Int]]`. Here's a (slightly modified for simplicity) Haskell version since I don't speak Scala particularly well.

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad.State
import Data.IntSet (IntSet)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IntSet
import Data.Maybe (isJust)

step :: Int -> State IntSet (Maybe [Int])
step i = do
    set <- get
    if not (IntSet.member i set)
    then do
        modify $ IntSet.insert i
        return $ Just [i, i*10, i*100]
    else return Nothing

run xs = filter isJust $ flip evalState IntSet.empty $ mapM step xs

main = do
    let result = run [1,2,1,3]
    print result
```

What you really want is `mapM` or whatever Scala's equivalent is. Then just run the State action and remove the Nothing values.